# What does that mean if my LED light bulb starts blinking when I turned it on?

Tags: lighting, led

I have an LED light bulb: [Philips 60W incandescent equivalent](http://www.usa.lighting.philips.com/pwc_li/us_en/connect/distributors/grainger/assets/GR-6107.pdf)

I've owned it for about a year and have been very happy with it.  This morning when I turned it on, it started blinking.  Not flickering, but a very deliberate one second on, one second off, one second on, one second off.  This continued until I fiddled with the bulb at which point it came on and stayed on.

It has never done this before.  I unscrewed the bulb and it rattles.  Something in it may be broken, but it still seems to work.    I couldn't find anything on the Philips website about this type of behavior.  Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: All I can find is that it's still under warranty. I found a reference to a 3yr and 6yr depending on when exactly you purchased it so it should still be covered either way.

Comment: Does it still happen if you screw it in firmly, or screw it into a different fixture socket? I have had non-LED bulbs slowly unscrew themselves untill they are only just in contact and then, they blink.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I called Philips about this issue.   They said that it indicates that the bulb is broken and needs to be replaced.  Some LED bulbs have enough electronics in them that they are able to have diagnostic circuits and to report errors in this manner.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with my Phillips LED bulbs as well. Good to know that this is a deliberate act and not faulty sockets/wiring!

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller: About the diagnostic, I had a good laught at it. I'm sorry, but the calling about the issue was not the "right call". Those persons only know to follow a book. You need a tehnician to fix it. The rattling is most certaintly of broken plastic because of the internal heating. And the blinking light is probably because of the capacitors ESR like Taruga said below.

Comment: I have a led bulb that only flashes once after I switch the lights on (it used to work) and I used to switch the lights on and off fast

Comment: Sounds like this is the right answer for this particular bulb, as it's probably how Philips communicates to the user that the bulb needs to be replaced.  When the flickering is less regular, it may be the dimmer switch.

Comment: Nobody mentioned that it could be the amp or the resistance  is too low when for instance you use a  dimmer switch. In my case my Phillips bulbs needed the dimmer to be at least 30% or higher to avoid the blink

Answer (score 6):

I experienced similar effect, but affecting a number of led lights on the same circuit where incandescent lights worked fine. Turns out it was a poor connection on the common neutral return.

Comment: +1. I get blinking on some of my LEDs when I turn the dimmer down too far. Basically, if the voltage is low the bulb becomes a relaxation oscillator -- it charges up to the point where it can light the LED, turns the light on, drains itself and repeats the process. Actually rather pretty since this is a 16-bulb chandelier... So, yeah, not getting a reliable power supply can certainly cause that effect, where incandescents would just be dimmer than expected.

Comment: @keshlam - Same here. Just had this happen yesterday with a blinking LED bulb. It is a non dimmable bulb, and somehow the dim setting was set too low. When I turned it up, the bulb working fine again.

Answer (score 5):

I've repaired 3 of my LED lights that were blinking by replacing both electrolytic capacitors. Capacitance was OK, but the capacitor resistance (ESR)  was too high on both of them

Comment: Can you include instructions for doing so?   I wouldn't be able to do that without a detailed walkthrough.

Comment: The ones I've repaired are not Philips but another brand. Check if you can unscrew the led lamp to reveal the electronics and take a photo. It should be exactly the same problem, capacitors! They don't last for ever. If you don't have any experience with soldering and removing/replacing electronic components then stop :)

Comment: @Taruga you should mention that the capacitors might have a charge after taking it apart. I've done that (being shocked by them) a few times :). Also, that inside the bulb when lit, there is lethal high voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure why but if you have a light fitting with more than one LED bulb you might try fitting a standard bulb into one of the sockets. That's what I did and it seemed to fix the problem across all the LED lights in the circuit. I think it may be something to do with the resistance of the light bulb. It worked, anyway!