# Why does an LED light turn on and off irregularly while the switch is in the on position?

Tags: lighting, led

We have had a LED light in the family room for several months now. In the past week it has started to act funny. We turn on the LED light and after a while it turns off and then goes back on and then a little while later off and on again.  The time between turning off and on varies. Is this normal after several months of use? Is this an indicator the light is starting to burn out?  A malfunction? Or a short in the wiring?

The light is not loose in the socket as we checked that.

What should we do? I do not want to have fire result from this.

Comment: If it were flashing at regular intervals, my guess would be that it's [telling you that it's broken](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/37406/12620). Since it's flashing at irregular intervals, my guess is still that it's broken, and isn't healthy enough to realize that it's broken (which sounds like an oxymoron). If it were on a dimmer circuit, then it could be a problem with a non-LED compatible dimmer, but that's not the case on a switched outlet.

Comment: @Johnny That would have made a good answer, especially as a contrast between this post and the other one about regular blinking. In future, please post your information as an answer so that it can be voted on and possibly accepted; that way, the question won't [come back to haunt us](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/949/22).

Comment: I'm having this problem on an LED-compatible dimmer circuit with 4 LED bulbs, but only one socket exhibits the problem. Swapping bulbs confirms that it's the socket which is problematic. Thumping or slightly twisting the bulb in the problematic socket causes the light to come back on before it resumes the irregular on-off pattern.

Comment: I have the same problem, seems to me that there is probably a capacitor that is under rated and is about to break soon. I will open my lamps up and check that to see if I can fix it. They probably do this so people will buy more lamps, cos any stores wont replace lamps if they go bad after a couple of months. And you would never even save the recipt that long either.

Comment: In our family room I have 2 sections of lights. One being 4- LED's on a dimmer. Only one flashes on & off, usually at different settings, i.e. very low & mid way. I tried another LED that is marked for use on dimer. I put that bulb in my living room & it works perfectly. With that said, it has to be in the wiring. So today or tomorrow I'll remove the fixture, [recessed] & check t see if I can pin-point any wiring issues. That's how you check the bulb. If it works perfect in another socket, or room, then it's your wiring & or that one fixture.

Comment: I have the same problem with retrofit lights in the kitchen , I took one down and took a temp reading it was 120^ degrees when it had just turned off and then turned on at 95^ , so I suspect that it's an internal problem? There is 11 light on this ckt and only 6 are doing this on off thing, I still have 120 volts at each light and no dimmers , I will call the manufacturing comp. and see what is the specs of these lights that I bought at Costco. And let you know I'm mr electric of imperial beach

Comment: Is there any new news on this? I'm going through the same thing right now. I just had the whole light fixture replaced and it's still happening. Just like you it turns of at seemingly irregular intervals, and when I bang on the ceiling or touch the bulb a little bit it turns back on. Did just buying a new bulb solve the problem? My main concern is that the light socket just isn't "compatible" with LED.

Comment: I have several LED lighting systems in my home.  The ones that do not have a dimmer never seem to have a problem.  However nearly system that has a dimmer has the problem of flickering/strobe/on/off bulbs, even after replacing them with new and different mfr bulbs.  The solution that has worked for me is by placing one NON-LED bulb in the system.  Once put in, the rest of the LED bulbs stop flickering/strobe/on/off.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The LED light bulb is malfunctioning and needs to be replaced.

There are several possible causes of the malfunction, but the bottom line is that it is no longer functioning according to specification.

Some stores have good return policies to handle this sort of issue.  In addition, some bulb manufacturers provide a replacement warranty.  One of those options may help you get a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Things that happen on a 5-60 minute timescale are generally thermal.

LED *emitters proper* are very tiny. They must remain cool and are rather sensitive to overheat. Your LED-based light bulb has a big heat sink to remove heat from the emitter proper.  Heat moves through a heat sink proportional to the *difference* in temperature.  So as the air around the heat sink gets warmer, the heat sink loses effectiveness.

If your lamp has a confined space, or if it is a downlight with no ventilation, it can capture heat (heat rises) and the heatsink will not cool properly.

Better LEDs have thermal detection and will shut off to spare the LED emitter from overheat.  That being pretty much the only way to kill an LED emitter; they will certainly outlive all of us.